# Runtime error 1004 while workbook.open method

Tags: vba, excel

```
Public Sub test()

Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim Conswbk As Workbook
Dim Temppath As String
Dim PayTemp As String
Dim Path As String
Dim lstactrow As String

Path = "C:\Users\mathew.m.1\Desktop\New folder\"

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

 Set Conswbk = ThisWorkbook

 Conswbk.Worksheets("Consolidate Payments").Activate

 Cells.ClearContents

 Cells.ClearFormats



PayTemp = Dir(Path & "*.*")

'--------------------------------------------
'OPEN EXCEL FILES


Do While PayTemp > ""  'IF NEXT FILE EXISTS THEN


    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Path & PayTemp)
     '
    Range("A12:M1000").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Conswbk.Worksheets("Consolidate Payments").Activate
    lstactrow = Conswbk.Worksheets("Consolidate Payments").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("B" & lstactrow).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)

    Conswbk.Worksheets("Consolidate Payments").Range("A" & lstactrow).Select
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = PayTemp

    wbk.Close True
    Set wbk = Nothing

    PayTemp = Dir
Loop

MsgBox ("Done!!!")

End Sub
```

First time the workbook opens. However, after the loop second time it doesn't. Need help.

Comment: Remove `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` until you have it working, you may be masking Excel messages that would help you resolve the issue. Especially since you're using `Cells()` (without the leading `.` refers to the current workbook), `.Activate` and `.Select`. You're probably on the wrong workbook when you're using these.

Comment: freeman that didnt helped is there any other way?

Comment: Did it show you any error messages? Did you walk through in debug one line at a time to ensure you're always looking at the correct sheet? Any other error jump out at you while going through in debug?

Comment: there is no other error. first time the workbook open. it is after the loop when the file name changes it show 1004 error

Comment: And what line was it on when the error showed up? What file name was it? are you 100% certain that the file exists? Do all the variables look to be correct when the error pops up, or by inspecting them in debug, does something jump out at you?

Comment: Just an observation, doesn't,`paytemp` already include the path. so if you have `Workbooks.Open(Path & PayTemp)`
are you not indicating the path twice?

Answer (score 0):

This will get rid of the `Active*` and `.select` references so you're not worried about which worksheet/workbook is which. Note the comment about row/col order, I can never remember off the top of my head which comes first - you may have to switch them.

```
Public Sub test()

Dim wbk As Workbook 
Dim Conswbk As Workbook 
Dim ConsWS as Worksheet
Dim Temppath As String 
Dim PayTemp As String 
Dim Path As String 
Dim lstactrow As String

Path = "C:\Users\mathew.m.1\Desktop\New folder\"
'Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set Conswbk = ThisWorkbook
Set ConsWS = Conswbk.Worksheets("Consolidate Payments")
ConsWS.UsedRange.Cells.ClearContents
ConsWS.UsedRange.Cells.ClearFormats

PayTemp = Dir(Path & ".")

'-------------------------------------------- 'OPEN EXCEL FILES
Do While PayTemp > "" 'IF NEXT FILE EXISTS THEN
  Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Path & PayTemp)
  wbk.Range("A12:M1000").copy
  'Range("A12:M1000").Select
  'Selection.Copy
  'Conswbk.Worksheets("Consolidate Payments").Activate
  lstactrow = ConsWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
  Consws.cells(2,lstactrow+1).paste  'note, may have row/col switched, can never remember
  'Range("B" & lstactrow).Select
  'ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
  'ActiveCell.PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
  consWB.cells(1,lstactrow+1) = PayTemp
  'Conswbk.Worksheets("Consolidate Payments").Range("A" & lstactrow).Select
  'Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
  'ActiveCell.Value = PayTemp

  wbk.Close True
  Set wbk = Nothing

  PayTemp = Dir

Loop

MsgBox ("Done!!!")
set consws = nothing
set conswbk = nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: this method is not working. the copy paste is not working at all

Comment: "Not working" doesn't give me much to go on. Is it getting the right row/column? Did I get them in the right order? Is it generating an error?

Comment: Object doesnt support this property or method. thats what is shows when it comes to "  wbk.Range("A12:M1000").Copy" this line

Comment: change that to `wbk.worksheets(???).Range("a12:M1000").copy`. You'll need to specify which worksheet you're copying from. Don't know if `???=1` because it's the first sheet, or if there's a specific sheet that you're copying from that you can specify by name - you'll have to sort that out

Comment: This did worked. But any idea why that workbook.open method doesnot work the second time

Comment: Probably this: `PayTemp = Dir(Path & ".")`. `"."` is a wild card for _all_ files. Try changing it to `PayTemp = Dir(Path & ".xls*")` to limit it to Excel files.

Comment: is there any other way using "For". I mean making an array?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking or where you'd put that. Give it a try and if you run into an issue, post a new question. Did my last recommended change help?

Comment: no it didnt helped there is some issue with open workbook method. it runs the first time. But after the Paytemp string is changed before the loop then the next workbook doesnt open

Comment: I would suggest checking the value of `PayTemp` in the debugger before it attempts to open the 2nd file. Something tells me you're not opening an Excel file, and that's why it's failing.